# Cheetah Keyboard wanting permission to manage my email

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I keep getting popups from Google asking me to give permission to Cheetah Keyboard access to manage my email. I got so many popups that I sent Cheetah emails. I've not heard back, so I uninstalled their app but continue to get popups. How can I stop this?

Comment: You uninstalled it but you're still getting popups?! What process did you use to uninstall?

Answer (score 0):

I reccomend you run a virus scan with something like malwarebytes.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.malwarebytes.antimalware&hl=en